# progressdialog not spinning

Tags: android, progressdialog

here is the code, currently the progressdialog is shown if user click the button, and the 'ring' is not spinning. but if i paste the progreedialog's code under onCreate, the 'ring' will spin once the screen is loaded. help me find where went wrong..

StaffChoice class:

```
   public class StaffChoice extends Activity {

    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{                   
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.staffchoices);
}

public void onClickCategory(final View view)
{       
    final ProgressDialog progress=ProgressDialog.show(this, "Please wait", "Loading ...", true);

    new Thread()
    {
        public void run()
        {               
            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Category.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            progress.dismiss();                     
        }
    }.start();
}
}
```

onCreate in Category class:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.category);
        final ListView lvCategory = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvCategory);

        SoapObject Request = new SoapObject (NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

        soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
        soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);

        AndroidHttpTransport aht = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);

        try
        {
            aht.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);
            SoapObject resultString = (SoapObject) soapEnvelope.getResponse();

            final String[] strCategory = new String[resultString.getPropertyCount()];

            for(int i =0; i<resultString.getPropertyCount(); i++)
            {
                SoapObject array = (SoapObject) resultString .getProperty(i);
                strCategory[i] = array.getProperty(0).toString();   //get category
            }
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, strCategory);
            lvCategory.setAdapter(adapter);

            lvCategory.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, final View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {                    
                        Intent intent = new Intent(arg1.getContext(), CategoryGames.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                }               
            });
        }

        catch(Exception e)
        {               
            String[] items = { "No Internet Connection, Please try again" };            
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
            lvCategory.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
```

Comment: from where u have called the  onClickcategory() method ?

Comment: from the xml... android:onClick="onClickCategory"

Comment: you have no any task in `run()` method and thread start and goes to handler ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of Thread, i use AsyncTask at the new intent

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
      new loadPage().execute(null, null, null);             
    }

    public class loadPage extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void> {

        private ProgressDialog pdia;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            super.onPreExecute();
            pdia = new ProgressDialog(AppDetails.this);
               pdia.setMessage("Loading...");
              pdia.show();
            }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        pdia.dismiss();
         }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to put Task or Time in thread while thread is running ,progress Dialog is showing,But when Task/Time is complete progressDialog dismiss.

Its better to use [AsynTask in Android](http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/android-asynctask-example.html) rather than Thread.

```
     new Thread()
            {
                public void run()

            {
                try{
                      Thread.sleep(10*1000);  //10 seconds

                   }catch(Exception e){
             } 
                handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);           
            }


           }.start();
```

Comment: so users need to wait for 10sec for the 'fake-spinning' before they can go to the next screen? i dun think this is a good solution. thanks though :)

Comment: its just example, how many time you want to wait going to next screen.and if you dont wait then no need to put thread.

Comment: actually it get the data from internet, so the 'waiting period' is very depends on the internet connection itself :)

Comment: so put that in run method i write in answer also Task.see this tuts http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/android-customized-listview.html

Comment: hey @melvintcs I got the same problem as u have, so did u figure it out yet? I need the solution as well, if u have any idea please reply me , thanks